# Is it possible to query systemd services not having Restart=always?

Tags: systemd

I would like to make sure all our services have `Restart=always`.

A list of services with the `Restart` value would be fine too, I could use grep on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [drop-in config files](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) to override this value.

For unit `thing.service` create `/etc/systemd/system/thing.service.d/restart.conf` containing

```
[Service]
Restart=always
```

Comment: My question is more about if there's a command line tool to get the current value of the restart attribute. So I can easily audit that it's set correctly system wide.